# C - I get an "array size missing" error, am I declaring the arrays wrong?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm confused with declaring arrays. If I enter a size, ie `good[200]`, the answer will just return `200`.
The program essentially takes 10 integers from user and returns which are of particular ranges of numbers. I thought of doing that by collecting the numbers through arrays and then returning the length of those arrays as the answer.

```
int n[10], i, j, excellent[], good[], poor[];
printf("Input 10 integers\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (n[j] > 80) {
        excellent[j] = n[j];
    }
    if (n[j] >= 60 && n[j] <= 79) {
        good[j] = n[j];
    }
    if (n[j] < 60) {
        poor[j] = n[j];
    }
}
printf("%lu are excellent\n", (sizeof(excellent) / sizeof(excellent[0])));
printf("%lu are good\n", (sizeof(good) / sizeof(good[0])));
printf("%lu are poor\n", (sizeof(poor) / sizeof(poor[0])));
```

Comment: `excellent[], good[],poor[]` array size missing refers to those. You need to give it a size either explicitly or via an initializer.

Comment: You do need to include the size, eg. `good[200]`.  The size will then be 200 elements.  If you want to show how many you've actually used, you'll have to keep track of that separately.

Comment: @Piegoose  Why do you not want to use `int excellent[10],good[10],poor[10];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in C have a fixed size that must be specified at the time the array is defined, either explicitly by giving a size between `[` and `]` or implicitly by the number of element the array is initialized with.  They *do not* have a dynamic size that increases with each element added.

You should give each array a size of 10 to match the input array, and keep track of the number of valid element in each array with separate variables as counters.

```
int n[10],excellent[10],good[10],poor[10];
int i, j, excellent_cnt = 0, good_cnt = 0, poor_cnt = 0;

printf("Input 10 integers\n");
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    scanf("%d",&n[i]);}
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
    if(n[j]>80){
        excellent[excellent_cnt++] = n[j];}
    if(n[j]>=60 && n[j]<=79){
        good[good_cnt++] = n[j];}
    if(n[j]<60){
        poor[poor_cnt++] = n[j];}
}

printf("%lu are excellent\n", excellent_cnt);
printf("%lu are good\n", good_cnt);
printf("%lu are poor\n", poor_cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize `excelent[]` `good[]` and `poor[]` with a defined size exactly the same way that `n[]` (write `int excelent[your size]`, same for `poor[]` and `good[]`).

In C, arrays always had a fixed size, if you want variable size, maybe you should create a custom data structure working as [list in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you're only allowed to omit the array size in a couple of circumstances:

- when the array is initialized `char s[] = "hello"; int a[] = {1, 2, 3};`
- when it's only a declaration, not a definition `extern int a[];`
- as the trailing member of a struct: `struct foo { char data };
- in function arguments (but that's actually a pointer, not an array)